# How can I have an unlimited history in zsh?

Tags: zsh, command-history

I want an unlimited history file in **zsh**. As far as I know I can only set HISTSIZE and SAVEHIST to a big number.

Comment: You can't, see the same question on the zsh mailing list: http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2013/msg00689.html

Comment: @mpy Can you make this into an answer?

Comment: @MarlonRichert: Please feel free to summarize the discussion on the mailings list I linked as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

First off, it is unfortunately not possible to have unlimited history for one purely practical reason: It is not possible for history to occupy more memory than you have. Removing the limit somehow would not be wise.

However, that aside, if you really want to set it as large as you can, you will need to determine how much memory you have and how much of it you can allow to be occupied by the history (which is always fully loaded into memory, [or so I've heard](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2013/msg00691.html)).

But just for the sake of it, let's suppose the hypothetical scenario where you do have unlimited memory. Then you are still limited by the largest number that Zsh will let you assign to `HISTSIZE`, which is [`ZLONG_MAX` from `zsh.h`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/3d7215cc8277b39cd1e24ce5a04376d45bfbabf0/Src/zsh.h#L46), which is defined as `9223372036854775807`.